# Create New Column Based on value of multiple other columns (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new column in MySQL based on the value of the columns show in the image link. I want to make it so that whenever a column has value 1, it will add the column name to the new column. So for example, if columns "genre_drama" and "genre_comedy" have value 1, I want the new column to be something like "genre_drama, genre_comedy". Having trouble figuring this out so help would be appreciated!

[columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6nwB.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode [how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CONCAT_WS()` function, with comma as the delimiter. The value of each following argument should be either the name of a column or null, depending on whether the value of that column is `1`. The null values won't be included in the result.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', 
                IF(genre_drama = 1, 'genre_drama', NULL),
                IF(genre_comedy = 1, 'genre_comedy', NULL),
                IF(genre_adventure = 1, 'genre_adventure', NULL),
                ...) AS genres
FROM yourTable
```

If you don't want to type this all out, you can construct the query dynamically using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: Damn I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this for every column but I see. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem if you had a better table structure, like an attribute-value table instead of a separate column for each genre.